# How to get the name of ContentType foreign key in database

Tags: python, django, model

I have field like this below

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

class MessageLog(BaseModel):
    receiver_type = m.ForeignKey(
        ContentType,
        related_name="receiver_%(class)s_set", on_delete=m.CASCADE,null=True)
    receiver_id = m.PositiveBigIntegerField(null=True)
    receiver = GenericForeignKey('receiver_type', 'receiver_id')
```

I can access member like this, and both returns the number.

```
m = MessageLog.objects.get(id=1)

print(m.receiver_id) //  2
print(m.receiver_type) // 12
```

However `print(m.receiver)`

```
object has no attribute 'receiver'
```

I want to get the name of receiver_type name.

How can I do this?

Comment: quick and dirty, but won't be feasible just adding a __str__ method to your model printing out both receiver_id and _type? 
Also, usually a meta class is recommended while using generic foreign key, see here the example 
Unlike for the ForeignKey, a database index is not automatically created on the GenericForeignKey, so it’s recommended that you use Meta.indexes to add your own multiple column index. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#:~:text=There%20are%20three%20parts%20to%20setting%20up%20a%20GenericForeignKey%3A

Comment: looks like you made a typo (`receiver` iso `receivor`)?